# Split Single PDF into Sub Pdf's Using Php

Tags: php, pdf

Got a task to break a single pdf into multiple pdf documents using php. Till now i have not wrote any code because i am not sure which way to follow. But i will try my best to explain the situation here.

I have a pdf document with several pages and all i want is to break this pdf into multiple pdf's by passing the page numbers.

So lets' say i pass starting page as 1 and ending page as 10. The php will read the pdf from page 1 to 10 and will create a new document for these 10 pages.

Hope there will be a way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this in PHP alone; as far as I know, none of the PHP PDF libraries can do this. It's a task for an external tool.

If you are on a Linux server, there's [this approach on Unix.SE using Python](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf). Then there's the [`pdftk`](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442414-manipulating-pdfs-with-the-pdf-toolkit) command line tool, the "Swiss army knife for PDFs". Googling "split PDF pages" will give you even more options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with native php using combination of [FPDI](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI) and [FPDF](https://www.fpdf.org/).

```
$new_pdf = new setasign\Fpdi\FPDI();
        
for($i = 20; $i <= 200; $i++){ //excracting pages from 20 to 200
    $new_pdf->AddPage();
    $new_pdf->setSourceFile("source.pdf");
    $new_pdf->useTemplate($new_pdf->importPage($i));
}

$new_pdf->Output("output.pdf", "F");
```